# Authentication with AWS Cognito

Tags: feathersjs

I've been trying to implement AWS Cognito as an authentication strategy with @feathersjs/authentication but haven't had much luck with the libraries available.

What would be a good starting point to develop this integration? Cognito generates the appropriate JWTs, and the verification can happen offline by parsing the JSON Web Key (jwk.json) file and validating the key. I can get this to happen fine without using the @feathersjs/authentication library, but I'd like to take advantage of the features within that library (user lookup, error handling, etc.)

I've gotten this to work using cogito-express as an Express middleware, but that doesn't have the deeper integration that @feathersjs/authentication offers.

https://github.com/ghdna/cognito-express

Comment: I was looking for something similar and stumbled upon this person's work: https://github.com/florianbepunkt/feathers-cognito-example/blob/master/src/authentication.js, maybe it'll be helpful for you?